# define javascript in ascx control or on parent page?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am having some issues with javascripts that don't work. My asp.net 3.5 webforms app has a page that contains several user controls (ascx) which contain javascript. Not all of them work What is the best practice to put the javascript in ? in the head section of the parent page or in the user control? also do i always need to define it like this? I dont use any js framework here:

```
window.onload = function(){ 
//initialize js scripts

}
```

Comment: When you do `window.onload = function()...`, each time you're redefining the `onload` handler. If you're doing that, you'll want to declare it only once, or find a way to store functions that are then called in the `window.onload` handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`RegisterStartupScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx) in the controls and let ASP.NET work for you.  Also, this will prevent lots of problems in the event you have multiple instance of the same control on a page:

```
    String csname1 = "PopupScript";
    Type cstype = this.GetType();

    // Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class.
    ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

    // Check to see if the startup script is already registered.
    if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, csname1))
    {    
        cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csname1, "alert('Hello World!')", true);
    }
```

Comment: i just tried it but it does not show up? i got js enabled btw

Comment: You will have to post some code for anyone to help you further.  We don't know what you are doing or what your errors are.

Comment: the site is a bit too big :( what is a good tool to debug javascript errors?

Comment: Use firebug. The console tab will tell you where it is breaking.http://getfirebug.com/