# Calling a jquery function in a usercontrol from an aspx page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, user-controls

This is my first encounter with User Controls.

I have a user control that contains a jQuery function called Animate(). I want to call that function from an aspx page that contains the user control. Is that possible?

When I click the button in the following code the function is not fired and no error.  What am I missing?

Upload_Animation.ascx

```
<head>
<script>
function AnimateGif() {
    // do some stuff    
}
</script>
</head>
<body>User Control</body>
```

aspx page

```
<head runat="server">
<uc:UploadAnimation ID="uc1" runat="server"/>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div> 
<asp:Button OnClientClick="AnimateGif();" runat="server" Text="Do stuff" OnClick="btn_Click"/>

</div>
</form>
</body>
```

web.config

```
<controls>
<add tagPrefix="uc" src="~/UserControls/Upload_Animation.ascx" tagName="UploadAnimation" />
</controls>
```

Comment: Why do you have `<head>` and `<body>` tag inside `Upload_Animation.ascx`?

Comment: I removed them but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: You should only have `<script>` tag and `AnimateGif` function inside `Upload_Animation.ascx` since it will be placed inside `<head>` tag in the aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I cannot see any JQuery code in your source example. As I can see (correct me if I'm wrong), you are trying to call client Javascript function that is declared as Animate() and you are calling as AnimateGif(); Try to correct the name of the calling function to match the declared name.

Comment: That was a typo mistake when I wrote the message in here. Animate() is in fact AnimateGif() in my codes.

Comment: OK. I'm sorry. Something more important is that you cannot put head tag in the usercontrol (that would be violate rule that can be only one head tag on the page). Instead, for registering JavaScript function in some usercontorl, try to use technic described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031235/define-javascript-in-ascx-control-or-on-parent-page.

Comment: May I see the console log output from the browser? (for example in Google Chrome - F12, console)